# How to establish an SSH connection using Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssh

I want to make an SSH connection using Node.js or JavaScript so that I connect it through a web page and run the commands. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good library, [node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh). It supports promises too. Have a look at that.

Code copied from the official documentation:

```
var path, node_ssh, ssh, fs

fs = require('fs')
path = require('path')
node_ssh = require('node-ssh')
ssh = new node_ssh()

ssh.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    username: 'steel',
    privateKey: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
})
```

Or

```
ssh.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    username: 'steel',
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync('/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa')
})
    .then(function() {})
```

> Edit-I have tried this code in my system and its working

```
var path, node_ssh, ssh, 
fs 
fs = require('fs') 
path = require('path') 
node_ssh = require('node-ssh') 
ssh = new node_ssh() 
ssh.connect(
    { host: 'Your host', username: 'username', password: 'yourpass', 
 }) 
.then(function(response) {console.log(response)})
```

Comment: You can remove the privatekey parameter @Nandini

Comment: getting an error like this:   (node:584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: config.privateKey must be a string

Comment: Means I just created new file and tried to run the above code.

Comment: var path, node_ssh, ssh, fs
    fs = require('fs')
    path = require('path')
    node_ssh = require('node-ssh')
    ssh = new node_ssh()
    ssh.connect({
      host: '192.168.0.159',
      username: 'hduser1',
      password: '123'
     //privateKey: fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/NANDINI CHITTI/Desktop/Migration Tool/id_rsa')
    })
    .then(function() {})
    console.log('SSH connecting....')        this the code

Comment: Thank you @shubh . I got it. and if I want to run any commands How do I do that

Comment: You can execute commands in then ,look at the link I shared https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh